# Parametric Equation of The Moebius Strip

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

One of the classical parameterizations of the [Moebius strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip) is the following (see [DoCarmo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486806995))
$$
\psi(u,v)=\left( \left(2-v \sin \left(\frac{u}{2}\right)\right) \sin (u), \left(2-v \sin \left(\frac{u}{2}\right)\right) \cos (u), v\cos \left(\frac{u}{2}\right)\right)
$$
with $0 < u < 2 \pi$ and $-1<v<1$. The map $\psi$ is clearly continuous and it is injective. To prove that $\psi$ is a coordinate patch on the Moebius strip, I must show that $\psi$ is a homeomorphism onto its image. To this regard, I want to show that $\psi^{-1}$ is continuous. Nevertheless, I can't find such a map. After denoting by $x,y,z$ the three coordinates of $\psi(u,v)$, I have to express $u$ and $v$ as continuous functions of $x,y,z$. How can I do it?

Comment: Hint: $x/y=\tan u$, so you know $u$.  Now plug that into either $z$ or $y$ to get $v$.

Comment: $y$ could be $0$. In this case, I consider $y/x$? Can you write down a complete solution, please?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of a similar question by the same poser:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2907640/moebius-strip-parameterization/2907792#2907792

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that
$
2-v\sin\frac{u}2\geq 2-\sin\frac{u}2\geq 1
$
Hence $\arg(y+ix)=\arg(\cos u+i\sin u)=u$up to the usual multiples of $2\pi$ away from a branch cut ray 0 to $\infty$.

Having determined $u$, either

- $\cos\frac{u}2=0$, in which case in a neighbourhood we will have $\sin\frac{u}2\neq 0$ so we use $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2-v\sin\frac{u}{2}$ to determine $v=(2-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\csc\frac{u}2$; or
- $\cos\frac{u}2\neq 0$, in which case we use $z=v\cos\frac{u}2$ to determine $v=z\sec\frac{u}{2}$.

Now check they are actually smooth.